# What is the lifecycle of a Oracle SQL session?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I came across the concept of global temporary tables in Oracle SQL server. According to a [tutorial on global temporary tables](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables):

> The data in a global temporary table is private, such that data
>   inserted by a session can only be accessed by that session.

I believe this could allow for the following scenario: a client starts a stored procedure twice, filling up a global temporary table beforehand each time with data for the sp to process. The two computations don't interfere with each other, since each sees only its own data, as opposed to sharing data, as would be the case with a regular table.

However, it all depends on what constitutes a *session*, and when one starts and ends.

According to the [Oracle Database Concepts Glossary](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28271_01/server.1111/e25789/glossary.htm#CBAHEBIG):

> **Session:** A logical entity in the database instance memory that represents the state of a current user login to a database. A single
>   connection can have 0, 1, or more sessions established on it.
>
> **Connection:** Communication pathway between a client process and an Oracle database instance.

This didn't clear up all of my confusion, so here's my concrete question:

My application maintains a single connection to an Oracle SQL server throughout its lifetime. It executes multiple SQL commands/queries on that same connection consecutively, will each of these queries be its own session, will they share a session, or is it not that simply answered?

Consider this pseudo code:

```
Command c1 = new Command("insert into TMP_TABLE (FOO) values ('TEST')");
Command c2 = new Command("select FOO from TMP_TABLE");

c1.Execute();
foreach (var value in c2.Query().Select("FOO"))
{
    print(value);
}
```

I have run the above in my application, and as expected, the command `c2` returned zero results. I take this to mean that each query constitutes its own session, which is what I'm looking for. But can I rely on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***What is the lifecycle of a Oracle SQL session?***

A session is a *logical* entity that exists from the time your application code connects to the database to the time it disconnects.

Sessions are independent of the physical (resource-based) entities that support them, such as connections, server processes, network connections, etc.

In the simplest (and most common, imo) configurations (i.e., "dedicated server"), there are 1-1 relationships between the logical sessions and the physical connections and server processes.  In more advanced configurations to support large numbers of users, physical resources (connections, processes, network resources) may be shared by/multiplexed among multiple sessions.

> ***I have run the above in my application, and as expected, the command c2 returned zero results. I take this to mean that each query constitutes its own session***

Unless your application code is disconnecting from or closing/releasing its connection between calls, this is almost certainly **not** the case.

Global temporary tables can be created with two options: `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` and `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`.

The first will cause all GTT data to removed upon a `commit` or `rollback`.  The second will cause all GTT data to persist for the entire session.

If you are NOT using `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS`, then you should *not* assume the GTT is empty at the start of a given call.  If you require the GTT to be empty at the start of the a procedure, you must `DELETE FROM` your GTT (or `TRUNCATE` it) at the beginning of the procedure (or the very end).

Note that even with this restriction (i.e., having to handle emptying out the GTT yourself within a session), global temporary tables are still useful because they still protect one session from seeing another session's data.  They also write less redo than regular tables, especially in version 12.1 and later.  In fact, as of Oracle 12.1, they need not write any redo at all, making them useful in read-only and standby databases.

#### Aside...

> ***I have run the above in my application, and as expected, the command c2 returned zero results***

For this to make sense, your GTT must have been created with `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` and your application code has some kind of "autocommit" feature enabled where it is automatically committing after each `Command.Execute()`.  Or else you're misinterpreting/misreporting your test results.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether your application maintains an Oracle session between calls or not, but either way you need to beware of assuming the global temporary table (GTT) will be empty on the second call.  Because if it gets a "new" session each time, what that probably really means is you are picking up a free session from a connection pool.  And the previous user of that session (which may be you) may have already populated the GTT for that session.  I have found this to be the case when using Oracle Application Express (APEX), which is an HTTP-based application framework.

You would need to call an Oracle stored procedure that used the GTT and then truncated (emptied) it (and/or truncated it before using it) to be sure of getting a clean slate each time.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle clears `TEMPORARY` TABLE contents on `COMMIT/ROLLBACK` operation.

So if your Command class emits `COMMIT` after command, it will also purge data in `temp` table and `next` Command does not see any content.

Comment: That's not necessarily true - it depends on whether the GTT was created with `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` or not. If it has be created with that, COMMIT will clear the data from the GTT. If, however, it's been created with `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`, the data will hang around until the session is closed. With shared sessions, that becomes a gotcha - you then need to manually remove the data when appropriate.

Comment: Thank you Boneist.Never actually thought about possibility of using GTT other then ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS...
At least that is how losing rows just between two commands is perfectly understandable. With ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS option I believe c2 would not come empty handed.


I mean. The c1 data was more rather lost due to commit (flush) of c1 then to using different session for c2 and that was the hint I tried to pass.

Answer (score 0):

Questions: "My application maintains a single connection to an Oracle SQL server throughout its lifetime. It executes multiple SQL commands/queries on that same connection consecutively, will each of these queries be its own session, will they share a session, or is it not that simply answered?"

If this is exactly how you describe it, then each query is run in its own `CURSOR` not session.  If you run a trace on your session and look at the raw trace file, you will see sections like `PARSING IN CURSOR` where your SQL is parsed and checked for syntax and permissions, then `EXEC` where it's executed on the server, then `FETCH` where your result set is fetched to the client, and `CLOSE` where the cursor is closed.  If your query has finished, your cursor is implicitly closed; however with PL/SQL and cursor programming, you can control/open/close your cursors explicitly. Implicit cursors can be reused as each cursor is allocated a number internally by Oracle.  Even if you open a single SQL*Plus connection and run a single query, oracle will allocate a cursor to it.

Example:

```
PARSING IN CURSOR #18446744071393882224 len=51 dep=2 uid=63403 oct=3 lid=63403 tim=29425147118918 hv=682153908 ad='3e6edfd80' sqlid='344kggsnajpxn'
SELECT "BDD_EXTERNALBATCH_ID_SEQ".NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
END OF STMT
EXEC #18446744071393882224:c=73,e=73,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=0,dep=2,og=1,plh=1849910378,tim=29425147118915
FETCH #18446744071393882224:c=9161,e=9402,p=0,cr=2,cu=3,mis=0,r=1,dep=2,og=1,plh=1849910378,tim=29425147128989
CLOSE #18446744071393882224:c=9,e=8,dep=2,type=3,tim=29425147129472
```

Now if you have connection pooling via Weblogic for example - then you have a number of SESSIONS open as defined in your connection pool, and each query goes through to a respective session as handled by Weblogic.  Sometimes Weblogic grows or shrinks the pool (within configuration parameters), and you will have more sessions created when the pool grows.

You can also run each query in its own session if you choose to do so, but this is a very bad idea and unscaleable for performance reasons. It's better to run as many queries and DML as possible within the scope of a session, or on the server via stored procedures and packages.

Regarding GTT (global temporary tables) - they are used within your session and deallocated when your session closes.  In addition to the obvious uses for GTTs, we use them for diverting certain classes of users over to different temporary segments (via a clever use of views and triggers), as in busy systems there can be very high contention for temporary segments.